# AJAX troubles, getting reply back from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Trying to create a Mail Chimp signup form using Mail Chimp API 3.0.

So far, I have a form that validates with the jQuery Validation plugin and posts to a PHP script using jQuery Form plugin. The PHP form is working based on multiple tests. I'm also sure data is passing from the form to the PHP script, getting data back from the PHP script to the page is where things are breaking down.

Here is the JS side of things.

```
  // jquery form for submitting —— this is where the part that is not working, I just want back an error code (e.g., 400, 404, 500) or status (e.g., pending, subscribed) and pass that to the var user_status.
  submitHandler: function(form) {
  jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
    url: '/mc_ajax/process_mc_getstatus.php',
    success: function() {


      // translate variables form php to js //
      function reqListener () {
       console.log(this.responseText);
      }
      var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
      oReq.onload = function() {
        //  var user_status = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      };
      oReq.open("get", "/mc_ajax/process_mc_getstatus.php", true);
      oReq.send();

      alert(this.responseText);
```

Right now, user_status is the variable I want to populate from the PHP script.

I was using 
        var user_status = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
But that caused an error since it the data is already parsed.

Here is what I have in the PHP file for sending data back:

```
    // $json_data contains the output string
    $json_data = curl_exec($ch);

    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    // Get status from JSON //
    $json_data = json_decode(utf8_encode($json_data));
    $user_status = $json_data->status;

    echo json_encode($user_status);
```

This is currently resulting in an alert that says, "undefined."

Comment: Check var_dump of every step, $user_status is likely not an object or array.

Comment: $user_status is definitely used in the php script. At the end of the PHP script there is a mail() to send an email to prove the PHP script is working. $user_status is used to populate part of the

Answer (score 0):

Got it woking. Changed JS to the following:

```
                // jquery form for submitting
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    jQuery('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').hide();
                    jQuery('#newsletter-form').append("<p class='inprogress'>Working on that for you.</p>");

                    jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                        url: '/mc_ajax2/process_mc.php',

                        success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $user_status) {
                            jQuery('.inprogress').hide();
                            // jQuery('#newsletter-form').append(responseText);
                            jQuery('#newsletter-form').append("<p class='thanks'>" + responseText + "</p>");
                        }
                    });
```